# How to Create a Personalized web Search application?

Tags: search, search-engine, user-profile, web-search

I have been working on this for a while but I am not able to figure this out .
I want to develop a tool/application for users (i:e) a personalized web search tool which produces results based on user interest .

Its really confusing for me how to start with?

1) How to create a user profile such that the profile should be used when the user is searching some keyword in search engine.

2) As I was saying it should user profile while searching ,i just want the particular application to use the user history also along with user profile which is used to produce results for the user.

The history and the profile should be unique for every user which means each user will have different history and different user profile ..based on that i need a search engine to produce the results

3) how to pass the query to search engine from application to produce results ??

I hope friends, please help me out to solve this ??

Answer (score 1):

As with any development project you need to break it down into tasks.

1. User authentication
2. User history
3. Get search results
4. Order search results based on user history

Each of these tasks will have DataAccess, Business Logic and UI. Try to work out how each of the tasks these areas will do and what rules should be applied.

For example - what happens if it's a new user and has no history?
What happens if there are no search results?

Break down the problem and solve it in small chunks.

Comment: Hi liath ..thanks for your reply ..I understood what you said but still i need few things to get clarified     1)how can i connect history and user profile any idea about this 2)which platform is easier to develop ,i am good with php ,javascript ..is it possible to work with them .please help me regarding this

Comment: 1) depends on 2 but presumably you'll have a list of saved searches somewhere? 2) That's up to you, first question is it web based or program based? Second is it going live and have you considered hosting prices options?